# Convert a converted number back to a date type format

Tags: sql-server, excel

I imported data from an excel sheet and the dates are column headers. The problem is that SQL Server changed the date into numbers (42845). I went back to excel an and changed the header format to date and saved it, imported the data back into SQL and same thing happened. Now I need to create a view with the dates in rows.I know how to use pivot and unpivot. What I need is how can I change those numbers into a date?

Comment: Be careful! Excel internally stores dates as numbers; they're only displayed differently. Try entering `42845` in your Excel sheet and then apply date formatting: on my machine, it shows `2017-04-20`. Now, internally, SQL Server also stores `DATETIME` values as numbers, but not with the same epoch offset as Excel. It's unlikely SQL Server is in any way at fault here, and instead the import process isn't importing into a `DATETIME` column. While you can convert an Excel date-as-number to a `DATETIME` in SQL (as the answers show) it shouldn't be *necessary*, and you may want to fix your process.

Answer (score 0):

Use cast function to convert the number to Date.

```
SELECT CAST(42845 AS DATETIME)
```

Check the output with the date in Excel, you may need to add +1 or -1 to the Integer value to get matching date as it is in the Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Excel numeric dates are the number of days since Jan 1, 1900, so this should do it:

```
DATEADD(DAY,ExcelNumber, '1900-01-01')
```

You might need a CAST...